# How to show byte array(byte[]) as file(pdf/doc) in codenameone?

Tags: arrays, codenameone

I am getting response from service as byte array(byte[]). in my app i want to show the file(pdf/doc) in app itself. is it possible? is there any way to save and view the file in codenameone?

Comment: It's unclear what type of file that is. E.g. if it's an image the answer would be one thing, if it's JSON the response is another & if it's a file such as PDF it's something else...

Comment: I want to show the file as pdf/doc shai..

Comment: Is it a "pdf" or is a word document "doc"? Maybe that's why it's unclear what type of file that is. Some resources: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/RvgMpMSrNI0 https://www.codenameone.com/blog/open-file-rendering.html https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-file-open-dialogs.html

Comment: I edited the answer from @tizbn with the details for PDF. Should work the same for word files if you use the doc extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code

```
String newString = String(byte[] bytes);
```

For PDF you need to create a file and open it using the native viewer:

```
FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
String fileName = fs.getAppHomePath() + "myPDF.pdf";
try(OutputStream os = fs.openOutputStream(fileName)) {
    os.write(myByteArrayData);
}
Display.getInstance().execute(fileName);
```

Comment: Added another option for PDF and refined style